# IE Display Data URI

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, data-uri

I'm currently using a solution which converts a pdf file to a data URI. The data URI is then set as an iframe's source and displays the pdf on almost every major browser, I have learned that IE 11 does not like this though. After reading up on it, i realize that iframes don't support data URI's as the source (nor do any elements other than an image URI) and that I can't set a source for an  element so I'm unsure how I could achieve the same with Internet Explorer.

I've tried using an embed (learned that it doesn't like data URIs either), an iFrame, initiating a download in a new tab of the file itself (to mimick viewing a it in the browser - no avail) and I'm running out of ideas but unfortunately a lot of people still use Internet Explorer so I'd like to make it compatible. Is there any way to recreate this behavior in Internet Explorer like other browsers do?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I've seen this done, but don't remember what it looked like.  One thing I remember is that there's also a way to specify the filename.  But that's about all I remember, and I'm not working where this was anymore.  Good luck with your searches!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up giving up on this for lack of time to research/test. The final solution was just as well I suppose. I ended up writing the PDF to subdirectory in the website and then setting the source  ofthe iframe to the download method of the file. Tad slower than my original implementation but it works for legacy purposes. **When will IE die!**